Cloud run issues with drivers not installed (all works on exactly same docker container locally)
Hi I run into some issues with cloud run and docker container.
I got a simple golang app which uses playwright which installs browsers.
the issue is that this docker file from official playwright-go github example:
# Stage 1: Modules caching
FROM golang:1.22.7 AS modules
COPY go.mod go.sum /modules/
WORKDIR /modules
RUN go mod download

# Stage 2: Build
FROM golang:1.22.7 AS builder
COPY --from=modules /go/pkg /go/pkg
COPY . /workdir
WORKDIR /workdir
# Install playwright cli with right version for later use
RUN PWGO_VER=$(grep -oE "playwright-go v\S+" /workdir/go.mod | sed 's/playwright-go //g') \
    && go install github.com/playwright-community/playwright-go/cmd/playwright@${PWGO_VER}


# Build your app
RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o /bin/myapp

# Stage 3: Final
FROM ubuntu:jammy
# COPY --from=builder /go/bin/playwright /bin/myapp /
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates tzdata \
    # Install dependencies and all browsers (or specify one)
    && /playwright install --with-deps \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
CMD ["/myapp"]

my app works fine and playwright can access website when run inside the docker container.
However if I push and deploy this exact container to Cloud Run then I get an error here:
This is how I try to use playwright
pw, err := playwright.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("could not start playwright new error: %v", err)
        return nil, errors.New("Error contact support.")
    }

and this is the error I get
{
insertId: "66e453a50001216509407d93"
labels: {1}
logName: "projects/my-project/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr"
receiveLocation: "europe-west1"
receiveTimestamp: "2024-09-13T15:01:06.034436024Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "DEFAULT"
textPayload: "2024/09/13 15:00:53 could not start playwright new error: please install the driver (v1.47.0) and browsers first: %!w(<nil>)"
timestamp: "2024-09-13T15:00:53.074085Z"
traceSampled: false
}

What am I doing wrong? and why Cloud Run is removing the playwright instalation? (I assume cloud run is somehow removing it from container when this exact container works locally without any issues.
Just to mention rest of my go app works fine on cloud run and as expected it is just that it is somehow removing the playwright.
I tried different docker files which did not help. I even tried to deploy simple app with only playwright and that did not work either.

This Dockerfile works (obvs some of it is for my Go app):
FROM golang:1.23.1-bookworm

# Install Node.js 18.x and npm
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && apt-get clean

# Create non-root user first
RUN useradd -m appuser

# Set up Playwright paths explicitly
ENV PLAYWRIGHT_DRIVER_PATH=/home/appuser/.cache/ms-playwright-go/1.48.2
ENV PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/home/appuser/.cache/ms-playwright
ENV PLAYWRIGHT_DOWNLOAD_HOST=https://playwright.azureedge.net

# Add all dependencies for Playwright
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libnss3 \
    libnspr4 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libcups2 \
    libdrm2 \
    libxkbcommon0 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxfixes3 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libgbm1 \
    libasound2 \
    libpango-1.0-0 \
    libcairo2 \
    fonts-liberation \
    libatspi2.0-0 \
    libxcursor1 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
    libcairo-gobject2 \
    libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0 \
    libgstreamer1.0-0 \
    libxslt1.1 \
    libwoff1 \
    libvpx7 \
    libevent-2.1-7 \
    libopus0 \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
    libharfbuzz-icu0 \
    libenchant-2-2 \
    libsecret-1-0 \
    libhyphen0 \
    libmanette-0.2-0 \
    libwebpdemux2 \
    libgles2 \
    libx264-dev \
    gstreamer1.0-gl \
    libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 \
    libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 \
    flite1-dev \
    flite \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

# Copy go.mod and download dependencies
COPY go.mod ./
RUN go mod download

# Create necessary directories with correct ownership
RUN mkdir -p /home/appuser/.cache/ms-playwright-go/1.48.2 && \
    mkdir -p /home/appuser/.cache/ms-playwright && \
    chown -R appuser:appuser /home/appuser/.cache

# Install Playwright and browsers
RUN go install github.com/playwright-community/playwright-go/cmd/playwright@v0.4802.0 && \
    playwright install --with-deps chromium && \
    playwright install && \
    chown -R appuser:appuser /home/appuser/.cache && \
    echo "Playwright installation successful"

# Copy the rest of the files
COPY . .

# Install Tailwind CSS and build the CSS
RUN npm install
RUN npx tailwindcss -i ./styles.css -o ./static/styles.css

# Build the Go application
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /app/server ./cmd/server.go

# Set final permissions
RUN chown -R appuser:appuser /app

# Switch to non-root user
USER appuser

CMD ["/app/server"]

